Error Creating New Image Asset - Android Studio
In Android Studio, when I right-click my "res" folder and select "New" > "Image Asset" (Same with "File" > "New" > "Image Asset", the image asset creation window doesn't show up and I get an Android Studio error report with the following error (works fine for Vector Asset):
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.android.tools.configurations.ConfigurationProjectState.getDeviceIds()" because the return value of "com.android.tools.configurations.ConfigurationStateManager.getProjectState()" is null
    at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationManager.create(ConfigurationManager.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ConfigurationManager.getConfigurationForModule(ConfigurationManager.java:153)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.DrawableRenderer.<init>(DrawableRenderer.java:80)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.wizard.GenerateImageAssetPanel.<init>(GenerateImageAssetPanel.java:210)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.assetstudio.wizard.NewImageAssetStep.<init>(NewImageAssetStep.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.actions.NewImageAssetAction.createWizard(NewImageAssetAction.kt:35)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.actions.AndroidAssetStudioAction.actionPerformed(AndroidAssetStudioAction.java:136)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.doPerformActionOrShowPopup(ActionUtil.java:339)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:313)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:362)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:313)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$performAction$5(ActionMenuItem.java:300)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:293)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$new$0(ActionMenuItem.java:68)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$4(ActionMenuItem.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:115)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:526)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:558)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3385)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6422)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4969)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4583)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4524)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2809)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4855)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:794)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:766)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:763)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:690)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:638)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:592)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)

Here is some other project information that may be useful?
Build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin") version("2.5.3")
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3")
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.myproject.example"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.myproject.example"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.datastore.core)
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0")
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha13")
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7")
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")

    // Nordic Semiconductor (Kotlin-BLE-Library)
    implementation("no.nordicsemi.android.kotlin.ble:scanner:1.0.15")
    implementation("no.nordicsemi.android.kotlin.ble:client:1.0.15")

    // QR Scanner
    implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1")
    implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0")
}

AndroidManifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <!-- Legacy Bluetooth permissions for devices on API < 31. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Bluetooth permissions for devices on API >= 31. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
                     android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
                     tools:targetApi="s" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".views.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation" />

    </application>

</manifest>

I've tried restarting Android Studio, restarting my computer, invalidating caches and restarting, and doing a clean build of my project. I don't really know where to start looking from here, if the problem would be in my build.gradle, AndroidManifest, or elsewhere in Android Studio.
I have another Android Studio project where the image asset window opens as expected. I tried comparing project structure to see any differences but the project it works on is much older and uses an older gradle version, older dependencies, etc. I know at one point the image asset creation worked fine since I used it towards the beginning of the project and it's now much much later and now that I have a need to use it again, I don't know what point would've caused the issue.

Did you find the answer ? Please hhh it's same for me
